Sent someone overseas money from their account to pay their bills
Someone overseas asked me to send money to pay bills out of his account. I did. What can I do to protect myself?

What did you actually do? What information did you have to provide? This may be theft, fraud, money laundering... or it may be an identity theft aimed at you. Or all the above

Why would he need you to pay bills out of his own account? Why can't he do it himself?

Your bills were paid out of someone else's account? You can reach out to those who got the payment and ask them to reverse it. It will likely be reversed anyway.
The money you sent is gone and you will never see it again. You'll need to pay your bills again, and maybe also fees due to the reversals and resulting late payments. If you reach out to them to reverse proactively you maybe have a chance to avoid those.

The question says that OP sent money from a third account, not his own.

How did you access “his account”?  If he gave you the username and password, then it’s quite possible that you logged into a victim’s bank(?) account and sent money to the scammers.  The banks, police, will track the source of the break-in to you.


Someone overseas asked me to send money to pay bills out of his
account. I did. What can I do to protect myself?

Somebody gave you a set of credentials to a bank account, and you transferred money out of that account according to their instructions.
Unless you have known this person in real life for many years, and you are 100% sure that you were actually in contact with the account owner, then you were likely a participant in a crime.
You need to contact the bank, and you need to contact your local police. Give the authorities the electronic conversations between the person who asked you to do this and yourself.
You need to hope that they think that you fell for the scam, and that you weren't a willing participant. If you were given any money to complete the transactions, expect that you will be forfeiting the money.

What you do is report this to the banks and police, now, so there's some evidence that you weren't deliberately committing fraud and so they have some slight chance of preventing it from going through.
